# I am using DataTables.net with MVC 5 and returning JsonResult. Page is showing table structure but not loading any data.Please have a look at my code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I did everything like adding jquery before datatables.js, changing settings of **datatable**. Still it's not working. Please help me out:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () {
        location = ''
    }, 60000)
    $(function () {
       
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            "ajax": "EmployeeDetails",
            "aoColumns": [
               { "mData": "EmpID" },
               { "mData": "EmpName" },
               { "mData": "EmpMobile" },
               { "mData": "OSName" },
               { "mData": "OSVersion" },
               { "mData": "BrowserName" },
               { "mData": "Platform" },
               { "mData": "DeviceUID" }
            ]
        });

    });
</script>
```

```html
<table id="datatable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                   
                    <th>OS Name</th>
                    <th>OS Version</th>
                    <th>Browser Name</th>
                     <th>Platform</th>
                    <th>Device UID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                   
                    <th>OS Name</th>
                    <th>OS Version</th>
                    <th>Browser Name</th>
                    <th>Platform</th>
                    <th>Device UID</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm returning json string using EmployeeDetails method which is coreect

Comment: Edit: Is there a controller named EmployeeDetails with a default index action as that is what it's trying to call?

Comment: Can you see the datatables call in Firebug Net panel? can you see the returned json? What does it look like?

Comment: What is your version of Datatables ? In 1.10.x use `columns` and `data`. Also we need more information about the "not working".

Comment: EmployeeDetails is  a default ActionResult method, but i made it's return type as JsonResult and it is returning JsonString. Also i'm using Entity Framework 6.0 for database architecture

Comment: I'm getting error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function. In javascript console.

Comment: That means DataTables script is not loaded, make sure that file exists and loaded in correct order or use [DataTables CDN](http://datatables.net/manual/installation#CDN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution , actually i included jquery twice in bundle and on page too! removing from bundle did work fro me! Thanks for suggestions. Also i applied datatables to default MVC table structure and it worked too!